# gnome shell 3.16 - how to add reboot butotn

Tags: linux, gnome-shell

I have a problem with my gnome shell 3.16.1 (on Arch linux)
I want to add a reboot button to the drop down menu at top right corner.

when I press  shutdown button - it shutdowns the computer.
(suspend button was added via extensions, but I cannot find an extension for reboot button), how do I add reboot button?
or modify shutdown button so It brings a menu where there is a reboot option?

p.s. When I logged out, shutdown button bring a menu where I can choose to reboot or shutdown a computer. But I guess it because it is a gdm.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that`s not what you want, but you can simply reboot with pressing top-right corner, `shut-down button` and `restart button`. Or simply type `reboot` in your terminal.
P.S. There is no need in extension for suspending, 'cause all you need is to go to gnome settings and configure suspend on power button as so:
 [image]